# TabContainer displays Tabs only at windowresize

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I want to create a Tabcontainer and fill its TabPage contents programmatically, but the TabPages won't be displayed. So far my Code:

```
        _buildUI: function () {
            var bordercontainer = new dj_BorderContainer({ style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;", gutters: false, region: "top" });
            var tabcontainer = new dj_TabContainer({ useMenu: false, region: "center", tabposition: "top", doLayout: "false", style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;" });

            for (var i = 0; i < ki_KisConfig.widgets.movingwindow.calccount; i++) {
                var contentpane = new dj_ContentPane({ title: "Calculation " + (i + 1), content: "content", style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;" });

                //contentpane.startup();
                tabcontainer.addChild(contentpane);
            }

            tabcontainer.startup();
            bordercontainer.addChild(tabcontainer);
            bordercontainer.startup();
            do_domConstruct.place(bordercontainer.domNode, this.interface, "first");
            bordercontainer.resize({ h: "265px", w: "432px" });
        },
```

I've googled around and tried different things. As you cann see I'm setting the `doLayout`-Property mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876445/height-of-tabcontainers-in-dojo). I also use a `BorderContainer` like mentioned [here in the last posting](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/issues/214) and I'm trying to resize it after creating the TabContainer like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564858/dojo-widget-doesnt-render-unless-browser-window-is-resized).
It doens't matter if I'm calling the method in the `postCreate`- or the `startup`-function of the containing widget.

I'm trying to set the width and height via style or to startup every "sub"widget.

Nothing works and the TabContainer only gets displayed when I'm resizing the browserwindow or resizing it by opening/closing the developertools (F12). If it gets displayed it looks like I want it. The only problem is that the `TabList` has a size of 0x0 and the same with the `TabPaneWrapper` when I'm inspecting directly the DOM.

Has anyone any idea?

**Edit**

After calling startup only on the BorderContainer I get this result:
[image: failing layout]

The tablist layout is strange and also the content of the programmatic selected tab isn't displayed. Everything is again fine after a window resize:

[image: correct layout]

**Solution (summary)**

I retrieved the best result with defining the `BorderContainer` and the `TabContainer` in the HTML-template. Unfortunately the layout of the tablist still failed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7524165/2724509) delivered the solution for correct tablist layout: My widget didn't contain resize() so I added it and everything is now working fine.

```
        resize: function() {
            var tabcontainer = dj_registry.byId("tabContainerMW");
            if (tabcontainer) {
                tabcontainer.resize(arguments);
            }
        },
```

Comment: it is usually because the parent node has a size of 0. Can you make a jsfiddle so we can have a look ?

Comment: The parent nodes have a size bigger than zero. I'm ensurign this with setting the width and heigth and I checked it with dom-inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes to your code:

The `region` attribute is here not required. Its only used to indicate the position for BorderContainer children.

```
var bordercontainer = new dj_BorderContainer({
  style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;",
  gutters: false,
  region: "top"
});
```

You don't need to set a width and height on your ContentPane, let this do the TabContainer.

```
var contentpane = new dj_ContentPane({
  title: "Calculation " + (i + 1),
  content: "content",
  style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;"
});
```

I've created a sample for you, maybe this helps you out.

```js
require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
  "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(BorderContainer, TabContainer, ContentPane) {
  
  // first create the BorderContainer without any arguments.
  let bc = new BorderContainer({}, "bc");
  
  // then create your TabContainer with region center.
  let tc = new TabContainer({
    region: 'center'
  }, document.createElement("div"));
  
  // add it to your BorderContainer
  bc.addChild(tc);
  
  
  // then create three tab panes (ContentPane) and add them to your TabContainer
  let cp = new ContentPane({
    content: "My tab pane!",
    title: "My tab title"
  }, document.createElement("div"));
  tc.addChild(cp);
  
  let cp2 = new ContentPane({
    content: "My second tab pane!",
    title: "My second tab title"
  }, document.createElement("div"));
  tc.addChild(cp2);
  
  
  let cp3 = new ContentPane({
    content: "My closable tab pane!",
    title: "My closable tab title",
    closable: true
  }, document.createElement("div"));
  tc.addChild(cp3);
  
  // call startup on your BorderContainer. startup of BorderContainer will call also the startup methods of all children (TabContainer, ContentPane's).
  bc.startup();

});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<span class="tundra" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <div id="bc" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</span>
```

## Edit

As an addition:
I was able to create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pnxx0ce9/1/), which reproduces the failure. The problem here is that the `createDialogContent()` method is getting called after the dialog show's up. As I mentioned below in the comments section, it is important to create a dialog's content before showing it.

In this fiddle (bottom end of code) are two sections, which call both the same methods, just transposed. In the first snippet, the methods are called in the wrong order. Int the second snippet, they're called in the right order.

```
   // uncomment this
   createDialogContent(); 
   dialog.show();

  // comment this
  // dialog.show();
  // createDialogContent();
```

Comment: Thank you! The startup thing was it. If I'm calling startup only from the BorderContainer the TabContainer is displayed immediately. Unfortunately the layout is failing. After resizing the window everything will be displayed in the correct way. I'll post a screenshot as edit.

Comment: Ah.. I also removed the style and region stuff you mentioned at the beginning. I added it while playing around to get this stuff working. The remaining layout problem is not affected by these changes.

Comment: Do you try to add the BorderContainer to a dijit.Dialog? If so can you post, the code? Maybe the error is caused there.

Comment: I'm placing the BorderContainer on a Attachpoint. As initial postet I'm creating the BorderContainer programmatically and the domConstruct call does the placing. `this.interface` is the attachpoint I'm using. The HTML-template for the widget only consists of the div with the data-dojo-attach-point attribute.

Comment: Okay. So I would suggest, that you call your `_buildUI()` method in the `postCreate` method of your custom widget, save a reference to your created `BorderContainer` in your custom widget and then call `startup()` and `resize()` in your custom widgets `startup` method. Don't forget to call `this.inherited(arguments)`.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed

Comment: As you mentioned before, you are placing the BorderContainer on an attachpint. What kind of widget owns this attachpoint? Can you show this code? Maybe an option would be to create the bordercontainer and the tabcontainer in your template, and than add the panes programmatically.

Comment: I'm now defining BorderContainer and TabContainer in the template and the content of the tab will be displayed directly when opening the widget. The TabStrip layout still is failing. I can't define more in the template because the count and content of tabs has to be configurable. The attachpoint I used was owned by a dijitDialog and I can't supply some code because it's part of bigger framework stuff. Thanks for your help, I'll accept the answer because you helped me a lot and the other stuff seems to be a bigger layouting-problem. I'll try now to trigger the window-resize event.

Comment: Okay. I guess the problem is, caused by the `dijit.Dialog`. One last hint: Try to add your `ContentPane`'s after calling the dialogs `show()` method. Don't forget to call `startup()` on each `ContentPane`. After you created your `ContentPane`'s successfully, call the `BorderContainer`'s `resize()` method.

Comment: I already got the solution, see the Solution-Edit in the question. Thanks anyway :)